# Search Template issue

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

When I try to run this script, using Sense plugin from Chrome, I get error:

```
GET geocoding/_search/template<br>
{
"template": {
      "query": {
         "match": {
            "_all": "{{query_string}}"
         }
      }
   },
   "params": {
      "query_string": "test"
   }
}
```

This script is based on documentation:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html
However is not working. It gets this error:
...NoClassDefFoundError[org/elasticsearch/script/mustache/JsonEscapingMustacheFactory];
Version of elasticsearch I use is:
"2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: How did you obtain the 2.0-SNAPHSHOT? The issue seems to relate to the  fact that the `com.github.spullara.mustache.java.compiler` library is not in the classpath, note that it is set to optional in the elasticsearch pom file.

Comment: version was actually 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT. Thank you for hint!